# Installing CoresphereConsoleBundle in symfony 3 - Unresolved type conflict

Tags: symfony, console

I'm trying to install CoresphereConsoleBundle in symfony 3. Here is the steps I followed (from https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle) :

1) Installed through (composer require coresphere/console-bundle) - went well

2) Updated composer - went well

3) Installed assets - went well

4) Added a line in /app/Appkernel.php :

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true))
    {
    [...]
    $bundles[] = new CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\CoreSphereConsoleBundle();
    }
```

5) Added an entry in routing_dev.yml  :

```
coresphere_console:
    resource: .
    type: extra
```

I tried to access the console through http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/_console

All I got was this ominous message :

> Unresolved type conflict.

Nothing in the  symfony log that could cast a light on this. Googling it gives nothing.

Any help appreciated. Best Regards,

MC

Comment: I can't replicate your error. Nothing I can find about your error message: is a php message? Apache? Where/who print this message?

Answer (score 0):

Damn me : the error message came from the content management of the site. As the console is not recognized as a declared type of object in the database, it triggers an error message.

Thanks for your concern.